# DataTable contains strings with Hashtags when imported from .xlsx instead of .xls

Tags: c#, string, excel, formatting, oledb

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC Application where you can upload excel files.

The files contain a few columns, in one column we have some dates, which are formatted differently. The dates come with two different formats, the first is `M/dd/yy h:mm:ss tt` (**General** format) and the second is a **custom format**: `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm`.

When I use a .xlsx file, the cells which uses the **second format**, contain after the import `########` as String value, which is totally wrong. When I change the custom format to a predefined, like `Text`, the import works correct.

Anyway, when I **export** the .xlsx file **to .xls** and then perform the import the values of the cells with custom format are correct.

Did someone experienced the same problem at any time? Can someone help me with this issue?

I need to do this whole thing with a .xlsx file since a manual editing of the file should not required before uploading.

for "completeness", here is my code which perform the import from an excel file to a dataSet with one table:

```
public DataSet ExcelToDataSet(object value, String path)
{
    String firstDatasheetName = "";
    String connectionString = BuildConnectionString(value, path);
    OleDbConnection oleConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

    if (oleConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        oleConnection.Open();
    }

    DataTable dataSchema = oleConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    if (dataSchema == null | dataSchema.Rows.Count < 0)
    {
        firstDatasheetName = "";
        // throw new Exception("Can´t access the first Datasheet in your Excel. Please check if there is one!");
    }
    else
    {
        firstDatasheetName = dataSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    }
    String query = "Select * from [" + firstDatasheetName + "]";

    OleDbCommand oleCmd = new OleDbCommand(query, oleConnection);//OleDbCommand
    OleDbDataAdapter oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(oleCmd);
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    oleDA.Fill(dataSet);
    oleDA.Dispose();
    oleConnection.Close();
    oleConnection.Dispose();
    return (dataSet);
}
```

My connection String is:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\v0-0-5\\project\\project\\App_Data\\Data\\Import\\file.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I would think working with the Microsoft.Office.Interop, rather than a DataSet, would help with this problem.  Check this out, seems like a similar situation: [Import from Excel to DataSet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244971/how-do-i-import-from-excel-to-a-dataset-using-microsoft-office-interop-excel)

Comment: This whole thing should run on a server where Office is not installed

Comment: Can you post your connection string please.

Comment: Ok, that sucks a bit and makes things harder.  Can we see what the code looks like when you consume the dataset?

Comment: My connection string is added above now. When I access the DataSet I have the exact same thing like in the Excel sheet before, but the cells with custom format contain the "`#######`"-String - access over `dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["date"]` - which is `#######` - the next row would be the correct date, which has the general format

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that would give the error.  What does the data look like when you debug and examine the DataSet directly?

Comment: I have no error. The data was copied like it was in the excel sheet. THe excel sheet contains data, all colums are read as String - as well as the column where the date & time takes place. Anyway, some cells of that column have a **custom format**, the others are formatted **general** - where the custom format is used, I have the `######`-thingy in my dataSet, the dates from the general format is in the dataSet as it was in the Excel ...

Comment: I want to try and check this out on my end, will you post a snippet of what the date data should look like.

Comment: I just want the raw data like it is in the excel sheet in my Dataset/datatable - the evaluation and parsing to one format is done later and works, I just have a problem with the import ...

Answer (score 0):

It does that for numeric values, such as dates, when the column is too narrow. Make the column wider, or the text smaller, does that fix it?

Comment: You are correct for when the user opens excel and so on - but in C# i get Strings with values "`########`", where a cell which is too small can not be the problem, since we have no width when we work with raw data, which were not displayed

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were referring to the excel sheet itself. My bad!